Should the recent "Last Author" question be canonical?
A recent question asks about the meaning of "last author" in a publication. Should it be treated as canonical?

By treat it as canonical, do you mean slap a [tag:canonical-question] tag on it and make it community wiki?

@Anyon yes that is the intention. The scope could also be expanded to include author order in general by field.

We already have a canonical question that covers most of this ground. Rather than trying to maintain two different overlapping lists, my suggestion would be that we:

rename the original post to: How does authorship ordering work in field X?
if there is any info in the new post missing from the canonical question, edit to add it in, and
close the new post as a duplicate of the canonical question.


P.S. Glad to see you back on the site, hope all is well.

Still recovering from serious surgery. Only partly engaged here. I should have caught this myself.

@cag51 as your suggestions seems to meet with approval - will you be taking care of things or should we help?

@Sursula: thanks for the reminder. I did steps 1 and 3 just now. For step 2, we may want to give a day or two to see if any of the original authors migrate their answers themselves. After that, we can start migrating anything else -- help with this is very welcome.
